# The setup for computing the conditional (co)variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, covariance, variance

Please tell me if my procedure is outlined correctly for the following:

Given that we have

[image]

Show that

$$Var(\beta_{igj}|\mu_{gj})=\gamma_{gg}^j+\sigma^2_{gj}$$
where $\gamma_{gg}^j$ i the $g$th diagonal element of $\Gamma_j$.

#### Question

My question is only if I am setting up my calculation correctly, not to perform the calculation (but if one knows one a derivation, please provide a reference).
Am I correct to assume, that I should

1. Calculate the density of $$\beta_{igj},\alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}| \mu_{gj}\sim p_1$$
   which is done by  multiplying the densities from lines 1,3 and 4
2. Integrate $p_1$ with respect to $\alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}$, i.e. integrate these parameters out, ataining the result $p$
3. Compute the variance of $\beta_{igj}$ with respect to this distribution ($p$)

#### Edit in light of the discussion

Using the tower property, we have (we suppress the dependence of $\mu$)

$$E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[(\beta_{igj}-E(\beta_{igj}))^2\right]=E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[(\beta_{igj}-E(\beta_{igj}))^2| \alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}\right]\right]$$

but we also have

$$E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[(\beta_{igj}-E(\beta_{igj}))^2| \alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}\right]=\sigma^2_{gj}$$

This seems like now I must compute

$$E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[\sigma^2_{gj}\right]$$

This is the point where I am stuck now. How can I make the dependence on $\alpha$ and explicit? How do I proceed?Perhaps (wlog assume $\mu=0$)

$$E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[(\beta_{igj}-\alpha_{gj})^2\right]\right]=E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[\beta_{igj}^2-2\alpha_{gj}\beta_{igj}+\alpha_{gj}^2\right]\right]$$

Looking at only the inner expectation for now

$$E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[\beta_{igj}^2-2\alpha_{gj}\beta_{igj}+\alpha_{gj}^2\right]=E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[\beta_{igj}^2\right]-\alpha_{gj}^2$$

Inserting this into the outer expectation, we have

$$E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[\beta_{igj}^2\right]-\alpha_{gj}^2\right]=E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[E_{\beta_{igj}}\left[\beta_{igj}^2\right]\right]-E_{\alpha_{gj},\sigma^2_{gj}}\left[\alpha_{gj}^2\right]$$

But it doesn't seem I have accomplished much.

Comment: Your setup sounds fine - and in general probably a pretty good exercise to do, but you could also consider using the tower property of conditional expectations.

Comment: @Nadiels Thank you very much for your comment! Could you please tell me a bit more about it and how to apply it (the towering property)? Again, thank you!

Comment: Leaving the conditioning on $\mu_{gj}$ unstated you can use the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) to write $\mathbb{E}\left[ f(\beta_{igj}) \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[f(\beta_{igj})| \alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}\right]\right]$

Comment: @Nadiels Thank you. Am I correct (again, leaving conditioning on $\mu_{gj}$ unstated) that using $f= (X-E(X))(X-E(X))^T$ we have $$Var[\beta_{igj}|\alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}]=\sigma^2_{gj} I$$ because this is the covariance matrix in the first line? And sorry for the long exchange, I really want to get this.

Comment: You're welcome, hopefully that answer addresses what you are after. The question is a little confusing with regards to the dimension of the variables involved, but I think there should be enough there for you to work out a solution that makes sense. Although do ask if there is anything that is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function, $f$, of $\beta_{igj}$ you can use the [Tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) of conditional expectations to calculate
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f(\beta_{igj})\right] = 
\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ f(\beta_{igj})|\alpha_{igj}, \sigma^2_{gj}\right] \right],
$$
where the dependence on $\mu_{gj}$ is left unstated. Now you just need to marginalise out $\Gamma_j$ to get the distribution $p(\alpha_{ij} ) = \int p(\alpha_{ij}, \Gamma_j) \operatorname{d}\Gamma_j$ and the result should follow on shortly after.

---

Looking at your question you are asking to show that $\operatorname{Var}(\beta_{igj}|\mu_{gj}) = \gamma_{gg}^j + \sigma_{gj}^2$, the fact that $\sigma_{gj}$ appears on the right-hand side suggests it hasn't been marginalised out, i.e. you are looking at $\operatorname{Var}(\beta_{igj}|\mu_{gj}, \sigma_{gj}^2)$ where only $\alpha$ and the those variables below it in the model hierarchy have been marginalized out.

If we condition on both $\mu_{gj}$ *and* $\sigma_{gj}^2$ so that $\mathbb{E}\left[\cdot\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\cdot|\mu_{gj},\sigma_{gj}^2\right]$ then you get (I have dropped the subscripts for now but it is straight forward to put that back in)
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\beta^2\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[ \beta^2|\alpha\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[(\mu+\alpha)^2\right] + \sigma^2 = \mu^2 + \mathbb{E}\left[\alpha^2\right]+\sigma^2.
\end{align}
You should check the steps involved there and then repeat for $\mathbb{E}\left[\beta\right]$ and I think you will be able to show the result you want.

Comment: You have been great! I have one last question if I may, that still confuses me. Where does the need to marginalize $\Gamma$ out come in? In the sense, that if (for the right choice of $f$)$$E[f(\beta_{igj})]=E[E[f(\beta_{igj})|\alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}]]=E[Var[\beta_{igj}|\alpha_{igj},\sigma^2_{gj}]]=E[\sigma^2_{gj}]$$ wouldn't that leave me with only having to compute its expectation (according to the tower)? I think I am still missing the last piece...

Comment: Sorry I'm a little preoccuppied which is why this was initially just a comment, but chose the pair $f(\beta) = \beta$ and $g(\beta) = \beta^2$. Which should display the dependence on $\alpha$ and $\sigma$. See how you get on and I will come back and tidy this up this evening when I have a chance

Comment: what I am trying to convey is that the variance as a function depends on the location and so better to write is as $\operatorname{Var}(\beta) = \mathbb{E}\beta^2 - (\mathbb{E}\beta)^2$

Comment: I will try to solve it with the new information. I am grateful to hear you will return in the evening to help! I am still struggling with the dependence. But I will work on it while you are gone. I really want to get this, and am thankful for your patience!

Comment: I made an edit to the question, following on your answer. Whenever you get the time, please look at it. A million thank yous :)

Comment: Have a question regarding your initial "Show that ..." part of the question, i.e. the the parameter $\sigma$ doesn't actually seem to have been marginalised out. I just wanted to check exactly what we are conditioning before I address the edited question

Comment: That part was lifted directly from the text I am reading. It is the same in two different sources I found. Neither has a derivation though. But it does seem weird, now that you mention it. I checked again, and I copied it exactly. Perhaps a typo? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76856/discussion-between-leastsquareswonderer-and-nadiels).